# tqdm Multithreading Random Duplicate Progress Bars

Tags: python, multithreading, tqdm

I'm trying to have a progress bar for each json I translate but I'm getting random duplication errors using tqdm. I'm guessing race conditions but I can't figure out why.

main():

```py
 # Open File (Threads)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=THREADS) as executor:
        for filename in os.listdir("files"):
            if filename.endswith('json'):
                executor.submit(handle, filename)
```

handle():

```py
def handle(filename):
    with open('translated/' + filename, 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as outFile:
        with open('files/' + filename, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
            data = json.load(f)

               # Start Timer
                start = time.time()

                # Start Translation
                translatedData = parseMap(data, filename)
                end = time.time()
                json.dump(translatedData[0], outFile, ensure_ascii=False)
```

parseMap() (Problem is probably here somewhere)

```py
def parseMap(data, filename):
    totalTokens = 0
    totalLines = 0
    events = data['events']

    # Get total for progress bar
    for event in events:
        if event is not None:
            for page in event['pages']:
                totalLines += len(page['list'])
    
    with tqdm(total = totalLines, leave=False, desc=filename, bar_format='{l_bar}{bar:10}{r_bar}{bar:-10b}', position=0) as pbar:
        for event in events:
            if event is not None:
                with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=THREADS) as executor:
                    for page in event['pages']:
                        future = executor.submit(searchCodes, page, pbar)
                        
                        # Verify if an exception was thrown
                        try:
                            totalTokens += future.result()
                        except Exception as e:
                            return [data, totalTokens, e]
```

searchCodes():

```py
try:
        for i in range(len(page['list'])):
            pbar.update(1)
            # Translating Code: 401
            if page['list'][i]['code'] == 401:
                currentGroup.append(page['list'][i]['parameters'][0])
                while (page['list'][i+1]['code'] == 401):
                    del page['list'][i]  
                    currentGroup.append(page['list'][i]['parameters'][0])

blah blah
return tokens
```

This is what I'm getting. Unsure whats causing the issue.

```
files/Map011.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.1s] ✓
files/Map008.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.1s] ✓
files/Map020.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.1s] ✓ 
files/Map002.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.2s] ✓
files/Map001.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.2s] ✓
files/Map013.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.2s] ✓
Map023.json:   8%|▊         | 140/1698 [00:00<00:01, 1331.62it/s]                   files/Map004.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.3s] ✓
Map017.json:  40%|████      | 17/42 [00:00<00:00, 73.99it/s]                        files/Map003.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.3s] ✓
files/Map019.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.3s] ✓ 
Map015.json:  75%|███████▍  | 1252/1675 [00:00<00:00, 4364.80it/s]                  files/Map014.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.3s] ✓
Map026.json:  43%|████▎     | 136/313 [00:00<00:00, 1307.69it/s]                    files/Map023.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.2s] ✓
Map028.json:   7%|▋         | 15/212 [00:00<00:01, 146.15it/s]                      files/Map006.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.4s] ✓
Map030.json:  63%|██████▎   | 186/296 [00:00<00:00, 1509.57it/s]                    files/Map018.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.4s] ✓
Map017.json: 100%|██████████| 42/42 [00:00<00:00, 89.30it/s]                        files/Map005.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.5s] ✓
Map012.json:  73%|███████▎  | 1304/1779 [00:00<00:00, 3480.51it/s]
Map024.json:   9%|▊         | 37/431 [00:00<00:03, 100.03it/s]                      files/Map017.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.5s] ✓
Map016.json:   1%|▏         | 89/7080 [00:00<00:38, 181.16it/s]
Map025.json:  14%|█▍        | 148/1052 [00:00<00:02, 377.28it/s]                    files/Map027.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.4s] ✓
Map021.json:   0%|          | 43/10984 [00:00<02:14, 81.05it/s]                     fMap036.json:   7%|▋         | 71/951 [00:00<00:01, 604.80it/s]
files/Map030.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.4s] ✓ 
files/Map038.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.1s] ✓
Map024.json:  21%|██        | 91/431 [00:00<00:01, 180.67it/s]                      files/Map040.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.0s] ✓
files/Map032.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.4s] ✓ 
Map037.json:  24%|██▎       | 92/390 [00:00<00:00, 472.02it/s]                      files/Map026.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.6s] ✓

iles/Map021.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.9s] ✓
Map031.json:  88%|████████▊ | 580/659 [00:00<00:00, 655.48it/s]                     files/Map010.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][1.2s] ✓    
files/Map033.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.8s] ✓
files/Map031.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][1.0s] ✓
files/Map035.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.9s] ✓
files/Map024.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][1.3s] ✓
files/Map037.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][0.9s] ✓
files/Map036.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][1.0s] ✓
Map029.json:  23%|██▎       | 609/2617 [00:01<00:03, 662.47it/s]                    files/Map022.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][1.5s] ✓    
files/Map016.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][1.5s] ✓
files/Map029.json: [0 Tokens/$0.0000][1.4s] ✓
```

Comment: pbar.close() cleans it up a bit but not fully.

Answer (score 0):

pbar.delay(5) is the fix. Don't ask me how or why because I have no clue.